# Code to make a single MediaPlayer play more than one piece of sound in android studio

Tags: android, audio, buttonclick

Being a novice coder, trying to code an app that plays a sound on buttonclick in a fragment; successfully did it but I want to add more small pieces of sounds to play one after another. How can I add those sounds(sound2, sound3, sound4, etc) after that 'R.raw.sound1'? Please guide..

```
 buttonPlayAudioVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(mp != null) {
                    if(mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                }

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   //you can add all the songs in a array

    ArrayList<String> songsArray = new ArrayList<>();
    int position = 0;

    buttonPlayAudioVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer(songsArray, position);
        }
    });

   private void mediaPlayer(ArrayList<String> songsArray) {
    if (mp != null) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    }

    if (position > songsArray.size() - 1) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(songsArray.get(position));

        position++;
        mp.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
            mediaPlayer(songsArray, position);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Tonnes of Thanks to You for your kind suggestion. Please tell me how these codes can access the sound resources that are contained by the raw folder. How the arraylist can be created?